# An inequality in Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppse $A$ is a self-adjoint linear and bounded operator in a complex Hilbert space. Let $x,y$ be two elements in the Hilbert space such that $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$. How can I prove that

$$ |\langle Ax,y\rangle| \leq |Re \{ \langle Ax,y\rangle \}|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality is not true. For instance let $A$ be the identity and let $x$ and $y$ be any two unit vectors whose inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$ is not real. Then, the magnitude of $\langle x,y\rangle$ will strictly exceed the magnitude of the real part of $\langle x,y\rangle$.

For an explicit example, let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be orthonormal basis vectors. Let $x=e_1$ and let $$y=\frac{ie_1+e_2}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
Then $$\langle x,y\rangle=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}},$$
hence the real part of $\langle Ax,y\rangle$ is zero, whereas $\langle Ax,y\rangle$ has magnitude $1/\sqrt{2}$.